# Return clicked date value from calendar

Tags: javascript, calendar

I want to return chosen by click date in alert window. For example, if today is 12 April and I clicked 1 January of 2016 alert should show `2016-1-1`.

Here is my Javascript code:

```js
var Cal = function(divId) {
  //Store div id
  this.divId = divId;
  // Days of week, starting on Sunday
  this.DaysOfWeek = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
  // Months, stating on January
  this.Months = ['January', 'February', 'Marhc', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'Octomber', 'November', 'December'];
  // Set the current month, year
  var d = new Date();
  this.currMonth = d.getMonth();
  this.currYear = d.getFullYear();
  this.currDay = d.getDate();
};
// Goes to next month
Cal.prototype.nextMonth = function() {
  if (this.currMonth == 11) {
    this.currMonth = 0;
    this.currYear = this.currYear + 1;
  } else {
    this.currMonth = this.currMonth + 1;
  }
  this.showcurr();
};
// Goes to previous month
Cal.prototype.previousMonth = function() {
  if (this.currMonth == 0) {
    this.currMonth = 11;
    this.currYear = this.currYear - 1;
  } else {
    this.currMonth = this.currMonth - 1;
  }
  this.showcurr();
};
// Show current month
Cal.prototype.showcurr = function() {
  this.showMonth(this.currYear, this.currMonth);
};
// Show month (year, month)
Cal.prototype.showMonth = function(y, m) {
  var d = new Date()
    // First day of the week in the selected month
    ,
    firstDayOfMonth = new Date(y, m, 1).getDay()
    // Last day of the selected month
    ,
    lastDateOfMonth = new Date(y, m + 1, 0).getDate()
    // Last day of the previous month
    ,
    lastDayOfLastMonth = m == 0 ? new Date(y - 1, 11, 0).getDate() : new Date(y, m, 0).getDate();
  var html = '<table>';
  // Write selected month and year
  html += '<thead><tr>';
  html += '<td colspan="7">' + this.Months[m] + ' ' + y + '</td>';
  html += '</tr></thead>';
  // Write the header of the days of the week
  html += '<tr class="days">';
  for (var i = 0; i < this.DaysOfWeek.length; i++) {
    html += '<td>' + this.DaysOfWeek[i] + '</td>';
  }
  html += '</tr>';
  // Write the days
  var i = 1;
  do {
    var dow = new Date(y, m, i).getDay();
    // If Sunday, start new row
    if (dow == 0) {
      html += '<tr>';
    }
    // If not Sunday but first day of the month
    // it will write the last days from the previous month
    else if (i == 1) {
      html += '<tr>';
      var k = lastDayOfLastMonth - firstDayOfMonth + 1;
      for (var j = 0; j < firstDayOfMonth; j++) {
        html += '<td class="not-current">' + k + '</td>';
        k++;
      }
    }
    // Write the current day in the loop
    var chk = new Date();
    var chkY = chk.getFullYear();
    var chkM = chk.getMonth();
    if (chkY == this.currYear && chkM == this.currMonth && i == this.currDay) {
      html += '<td class="today">' + i + '</td>';
    } else {
      html += '<td class="normal"><a href="" id="dge" onClick="MyFunction();">' + i + '</a></td>';
    }
    // If Saturday, closes the row
    if (dow == 6) {
      html += '</tr>';
    }
    // If not Saturday, but last day of the selected month
    // it will write the next few days from the next month
    else if (i == lastDateOfMonth) {
      var k = 1;
      for (dow; dow < 6; dow++) {
        html += '<td class="not-current">' + k + '</td>';
        k++;
      }
    }
    i++;
  } while (i <= lastDateOfMonth);
  // Closes table
  html += '</table>';
  // Write HTML to the div
  document.getElementById(this.divId).innerHTML = html;
};
// On Load of the window
window.onload = function() {
    // Start calendar
    var c = new Cal("divCal");
    c.showcurr();
    // Bind next and previous button clicks
    getId('btnNext').onclick = function() {
      c.nextMonth();
    };
    getId('btnPrev').onclick = function() {
      c.previousMonth();
    };
  }
  // Get element by id
function getId(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

function MyFunction(){
  alert(document.getElementById('dge').text);
}
```

Comment: Please try creating a simple minimal example and avoid pasting your entire code ... help here :http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ... You could also use the "Code Snippet" feature of SO so that the members can assist you better

Comment: http://mes.gov.ge/?lang=eng - see calendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the calendar in the example, and all of the calendar dates have data-year, data-month and data-day set (as far as I could see). So a simple idea would be to attach an event to every `a` that has a data-month, data-year, and data-day set and then alert the date as follows ...

```js
$("a[data-year][data-month][data-day]").on("click", function(){ alert($(this).data("year")+"-"+$(this).data("month")+"-" +$(this).data("day"));})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-day="12" href="content.php?year=2017&amp;month=4&amp;day=12&amp;lang=ge" data-month="4" data-year="2017">12</a>
```

Furthermore, if your code is open to little more modification, then all the `a` tags that are dates could be in a class like `class="dateClass"` so that your selector does not get so complex like above, instead only looks for the elements belonging to this class ... Like the snippet below :

```js
$(".dateClass").on("click", function(){ alert($(this).data("year")+"-"+$(this).data("month")+"-" +$(this).data("day"));})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="dateClass" data-day="12" href="content.php?year=2017&amp;month=4&amp;day=12&amp;lang=ge" data-month="4" data-year="2017">12</a>
```

---- EDIT ----

Given the further request ( and not using jQuery this time ), you could add the date, month, and year to the `a` tag as attributes and also send the `this` to the function so that the currently clicked `a` element is sent to function (get rid of the duplicate id `dge` by the way) like below :

```
html += '<td class="normal"><a href="" id="dge" onClick="MyFunction();">' + i + '</a></td>';
```

becomes

```
html += '<td class="normal"><a href="" day="'+this.currDay+'" month="'+this.currMonth+'" year="'+this.currYear+'" onClick="MyFunction(this);">' + i + '</a></td>';
```

Then the below snippet should do the trick :

```js
function MyFunction(val){
alert(val.getAttribute("day")+"-"
+val.getAttribute("month")+"-"
+val.getAttribute("year"));
};
```

```html
<a href="" day="3" month="2" year="2017" onClick="MyFunction(this);">3</a>
<a href="" day="4" month="2" year="2017" onClick="MyFunction(this);">4</a>
```

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same `id=dge` ... That's not good, there should be only one element with one id... it's better to put a class to your elements say `class=dgeC` and write a handler for all of them like `$(".dgeC").on("click", function(){alert("test");});`